# Не работает прекомпиляция ассетов в Rails + Webpack + ReactJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой - не работает прекомпиляция ассетов в Rails-приложении

```
    MacBook-Air-mac:revamp-freelancify mac$ rake assets:precompile
cd "/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify" && RAILS_ENV=production NODE_ENV=production bin/webpack
/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:188
            chunk.sortModules();
                  ^

TypeError: chunk.sortModules is not a function
    at /Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:188:19
    at /Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3110:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1069:9)
    at eachOf (/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1117:5)
    at Object.eachLimit (/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3172:5)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:184:27)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at Compilation.seal (/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:579:8)
    at /Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:493:16
    at /Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:289:11
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:481:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelancify/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:452:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [cd "/Users/mac/development/revamp-freelanc...]
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/react_on_rails-11.1.4/lib/tasks/assets.rake:64:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => react_on_rails:assets:compile_environment => react_on_rails:assets:webpack
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Использую Rails, в нем React и Webpack. Из-за этой же ошибки не могу залить коммит на heroku. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо!

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/581#issuecomment-318023459

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в задаче

rake react_on_rails:assets:webpack

помогла команда

npm install --save-dev webpack@3.6.0